# Nativebase React Native why can't i pass a number on an input

Tags: typescript, react-native, native-base

I'm using react native nativebase and i want to pass a number to my input value but im getting an error that says i cannot pass a number to a string.

```
<Input
          keyboardType="numeric"
          onChangeText={(text) => setTarget(text)}
          value={target}
        />
```

Now if I do this.

```
<Input
          keyboardType="numeric"
          // onChangeText={(text) => setTarget(text)}
          value={"target"}
```

The error disappear.
This is the definition of the value

```
const [target, setTarget] = useState<number>(0);
```

[image]

Comment: Because in your code. You initialize the type of variable is number.
But in the InputText the output is always a string.
You can convert ouput to number or change variable to string  so you can fix it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You declared your `target` state as a number and the argument in `onChangeText` is always will be string. So first assign that number state as a string in input and when changes happen in value convert it to number as below :

```js
<Input
  keyboardType="numeric"
  onChangeText={(text) => setTarget(parseInt(text, 10))} // conver to number
  value={target.toString()} // convert to string
/>
```

Comment: This solution should be part of official documentation, creating number input is such a common task, yet this is the most clean solution I've seen so far

Answer (score 0):

For currency input (numbers only even using physical keyboard) using native-base

```
    <Input
      keyboardType="numeric"
      value={!isNaN(priceValue)?String(priceValue):""}
      onChangeText={(val) => {setPriceValue(parseInt(val, 10))}}
      placeholder={priceValue==null || isNaN(priceValue) ||  priceValue==undefined?"Set price/hour":""}
    />
```

Placeholder shows only input has no valid initial value.